# Vue 2 Composition API + Jest method testing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-composition-api, vitest

So previously I have a successfully working test with Vue 2.7 + Jest in Options API like this:

```js
{
  data: () => ({}),
  methods: {
    async someFunction() {
      const result = await this.hiWorld()
      return result
    },
    async hiWorld() {
      return 'hi world'
    }
  }
}
```

```js
test('helloWorld', async () => {
  console.log(wrapper.vm.someFunction) // [Function: bound someFunction] AsyncFunction
  const result = await wrapper.vm.someFunction()
  expect(result).toBe('hi world')
})
```

and after I converted it to using setup function, jest wasn't able to call it and throws a 5000 timeout (even after adjustments, nothing happens)

```js
{
  setup() {
    async function someFunction() {
      const result = await hiWorld() // it wasn't able to call this now?
      return result
    }

    async function hiWorld() {
      return 'hi world'
    }

    return {
      someFunction,
      hiWorld
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

and from `[Function: bound someFunction] AsyncFunction` it now logs `[AsyncFunction: someFunction]`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a mistake to use this.hiWorld in composition. This code shouldn't cause a timeout, make sure it's not caused by something else